# Create different types for a primitive property with Swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I have gone through some answers where we can use typeless schema in Swagger 2.0. However that is only for objects or arrays. How can I define a primitive property which can have both string or integer?

```
multipleValueHold:
    type: string
    description: This should hold both integer and string
```

Comment: See the ^ linked Q&A. It's about array item types, but the same idea applies to property types.